# Connected Lie group for which every connected Lie subgroup is simply connected

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, nilpotent-groups

Let $G$ be a simply connected Lie group. If $G$ is nilpotent, we know every connected Lie subgroup of $G$ is simply connected by Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula. What about the converse? If every connected Lie subgroup $G$ is simply connected, then is $G$ nilpotent? If not, can we classify them?

Comment: @user10354138 For simply connected nilpotent Lie group, there is no torus inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the group of matrices $\pmatrix{a &b\cr 0&c}, a,c>0$ every connected subgroup of this group is simply connected but this group is solvable and not nilpotent.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any classification? Must it be solvable? And you use that $\mathbb R_{>0}$ is simply connected which does not appear over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: I believe that all connected subgroups of the universal cover of $Sl(2,\mathbb{R})$ are simply connected.

Comment: How do you see that?